# logback specify the location of the default configuration file as a system property not working

Tags: logging, logback

`export logback.configurationFile=123` on mac os x got this:
"-bash: export: `logback.configurationFile=123': not a valid identifier"

Tried `export logback_configurationFile=123` that worked. but logback does not seem to recognize that env variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does logback even look for that variable? I thought it looked for logback.xml on the classpath?

Comment: it does. if I do java -Dlogback.configurationFile=whatever, it will work.

Comment: nice, I'm pretty sure that bash won't allow dots in env variables (bash being the default in OsX if I remember correclyt). There are shells that support this like csh and tcsh...

Comment: Wouldn't it be good enough to pass it with -D ?

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg what if it is an web app?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`-Dlogback.configurationFile` is not the same as setting it as an Environment variable.

The -D flag is a Java parameter to your program (accessible by `System.getProperty()`) while the environment variable defined by `export` will be accessible by `System.getenv()`.
Looking at the Logback code it looks like it uses `System.getProperty()` to read the `logback.configurationFile` value.

So in reality you have to pass the parameter to the JVM on startup, this means that you can set the environment variable to whatever you like and then just use it in when you start the JVM.

```
export LOGBACK_CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION=/tmp/logback.conf
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=${LOGBACK_CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION}
```

Comment: You can also use `System.setEnv(...` FWIW https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885787/setting-logback-xml-path-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

I guess that also that way should work. But I did not realy try it by my own.

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dlogback.configurationFile=123"
```

Then you would not need to set the opt on the call of your app. But the drawback would be that all running Java programs would use this setting.

Comment: Speculating does not help anybody. Try it out or don't answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following
Export your JVM arguments with logback configurationFile.

```
export ALC_JVM_ARGS="-Dlogback.configurationFile=logconfig.xml"
```

Export other things you need like main class and it's arguments

```
export MAIN_CLASS="Spring"
export MAIN_CLASS_ARGS="beans.xml"
```

Then execute your program

```
exec java $ALC_JVM_ARGS $MAIN_CLASS $MAIN_CLASS_ARGS
```