# Setting logback.xml path programmatically

Tags: java, logback

I know I can set the logback.xml path like this:

**Specifying the location of the default configuration file as a system property**

You may specify the location of the default configuration file with a system property named "logback.configurationFile". The value of this property can be a URL, a resource on the class path or a path to a file external to the application.

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml chapters.configuration.MyApp1
```

but how can I do it in code?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could use:

```
System.setProperty("logback.configurationFile", "/path/to/config.xml");
```

But it would have to happen before logback is loaded, i.e. something like:

```
class Main {
  static { System.setProperty("logback.configurationFile", "/path/to/config.xml");}
  private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

  public void main (String[] args) { ... }
}
```

Note: I have not tested it but it should work.

Comment: If you want to override any default configuration, this method does not work.  You need to reset the configuration using JoranConfiguration

Comment: Is it a relative path like 'application/test/conf/logback.xml' or a full path 'C:/application/test/conf/logback.xml'?

Comment: Depends on your project configuration - but if you are using maven for example, a relative path within the jar should work. So if you've put it in src/main/resources, just the file name should work.

Comment: if you deploy this to tomcat, app is not gonna load after tomcat restart

Comment: @syd I don't know Tomcat but, generally speaking, in an application server environment you should rely on the container logging system and not use your own.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. It goes with the default configuration instead of my logback.xml file

Answer (score 62):

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
loggerContext.reset();
JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
InputStream configStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(logbackPropertiesUserFile);
configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
configurator.doConfigure(configStream); // loads logback file
configStream.close();
```

Comment: I would upvote this as the best answer if you would add the reset() call.

Comment: Is this the only way to pass a logback setting file configuration ?  I alsways found the _ye olde_ log4j  BasicConfigurator relatively intuiitve.  Pass a file name and let it happen.

Comment: JoranConfigurator inherits from http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/joran/GenericConfigurator.html and there are 5 overrides for `doConfigure()`

Comment: @michid you have a better solution ?

Comment: If you use Spring Boot than the `org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringBootJoranConfigurator` should be used which is a subclass of the `JoranConfigurator`.
This class adds support for the Spring Boot specific parts like the `<springProperty>` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html).

Answer (score 11):

modifying environment variables might not always be feasible.
To do it properly see logback manual:

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#joranDirectly

Comment: Even this example is more complex than a BasicConfigurator.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to share what I did in the end with a Jersey-Spring app:

```
MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.addListener(new LogbackConfigListener());
        try { LogbackConfigurer.initLogging(servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/logback.xml")); }
        catch (FileNotFoundException | JoranException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

I also have to add, that I had to move

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.logback-extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-ext-spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.4</version>
    <scope>compile</scope></dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope></dependency>
```

from runtime (parent project in my case) to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Include another logback xml to change path in **logback-spring.xml**

include resource = "/path/to/logback.xml"

add data within **included** tags in **logback.xml**